# Calling a specific data key value from NSDictionary Issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

Calling a value from NSDictionary in the cellForRowAtIndexPath but I'm getting my data(parsedData) as nil. Please how can I get the data from NSDictionary key value?

```
var dic1 = NSDictionary()

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{
    element = elementName

    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("info")
    {
        symbolStr = attributeDict["symbol"]! as NSMutableString
        offerlStr = attributeDict["offer"]! as NSMutableString

        dic1 = ["symbolName":symbolStr , "offerAmount":offerlStr]

        pariteArray.addObject(dic1)   
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:    Int) -> Int {

    return pariteArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var parsedData: AnyObject? = dic1["symbolName"]?.indexPath
    var parsedData2: AnyObject? = dic1["offerAmount"]?.indexPath

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = parsedData as? String //nil
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = parsedData2 as? String //nil

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I can tell you why your code is wrong.

Here, you assign the values of your `dic11` as `NSMutableString` objects:

```
symbolStr = attributeDict["symbol"]! as NSMutableString
offerlStr = attributeDict["offer"]! as NSMutableString

dic1 = ["symbolName":symbolStr , "offerAmount":offerlStr]
```

Later, you attempt to access `.indexPath` of these objects:

```
var parsedData: AnyObject? = dic1["symbolName"]?.indexPath
var parsedData2: AnyObject? = dic1["offerAmount"]?.indexPath
```

`NSMutableString` does not have a `.indexPath`.

I'm going to take a wild guess here and assume that you actually wanted to do this:

```
var parsedData: AnyObject? = pariteArray[indexPath.row]["symbolName"]
var parsedData2: AnyObject? = pariteArray[indexPath.row]["offerAmount"]
```

Comment: I've tried to add your last code but I get this issue `NSIndexPath`is not convertible to 'Int'

Comment: It was more meant as psuedocode than actual code. I replaced it with `indexPath.row` so that the error you saw goes away. There's probably some missing `?` though.